# How to set color for individual link in WordPress / Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

If it is possible in Wordpress / Elementor to set different colors of links on the website? To set the preferred color of links on the wordpress page, we do it in the site settings -> typography. However, these settings are global so are valid for the entire website, so I am not able to edit the colors of individual links. I would like to do this because in different sections of the page I have different background colors and the font color must be different to be visible. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are you sing elementor free or pro?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with css.

Give a different ID to each section where you need to edit the link color from the advanced tab:

[image]

Each section must have a different ID

Then go to appearance >> customize >> additional css and try this code:

```
#my-id a {
color: #000;
}
```

Replace the #000 with your desired color and repeat that with each ID.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, Elementor allows you to specify the link colour at the column level - but not, it seems, at the text editor level. Select the column to edit it, click the 'Style' tab, and expand the 'Typography' section. Here, you can set the colours for Heading, Text, Link and Link Hover.

[image: Elementor column typography section]